# How to find accuracy of matrix multiplication with floating-point numbers?

Tags: matrix, multidimensional-array, floating-point, precision, matrix-multiplication

I am trying to analyze how floating-point computation becomes more inaccurate when the data size decreases. In order to do that, I wanted to perform simple matrix operations on different variations of floating point representation, such as float64, float32, and float16. Since float64 computation will give the most precise and accurate result out of the three, I assume all float64 computation to give the expected result (i.e., error = 0).

The issue is that when I compare the calculated result with the expected result, I don't have an exact idea of how to quantify all the individual errors that I get into a single metric. I know about certain ways to go about it, such as finding the error mean, or the sum of square of errors (SSE), but I just wanted to know if there was a standard way of calculating the overall error of a given matrix computation.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps a variant of the condition number can be helpful? See here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Condition_number#Matrices

Answer (score 0):

> if there was a standard way of calculating the overall error of a given matrix computation.

Consider the case when a matrix is size 1.  Then we are in a familiar 1 dimension domain.

How to compare `y_computed_as_float` vs `y_expected`?  Even in this case, there is not a standard of how these should compare as floating point numbers. Subtract? Divide? It is often context sensitive.  So "no" to OP's question.

Yet there are common practices. So a potential "yes" to OP question for select cases.

---

Floating point computations are often assessed by the difference between computed and math expected values *scaled* by the [Unit in the last place](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unit_in_the_last_place)<sup>*</sup>.

```
error = (y_computed_as_float - y_expected)/ulpf((float) y_expected);
```

For an N dimension matrix, the matrix error could use a [root mean square](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Root_mean_square) of the N<sup>2</sup> element errors.

---

<sup>*</sup> Scaling by ULP has some issues near each power of 2 and more near 0.0.  There are ways to mitigate that, but we a getting into the weeds.